# How to pass { into cURL

Tags: curl, special-characters

I need to read the public data from https://github.com/Fairlay/PublicAPI
like 
http://31.172.83.181:8080/free/markets/{"Cat":1,"OnlyActive":true,"NoZombie":true,"ToID":100000}'

and I'm trying to do it

```
curl --compressed -o filename.txt 'http://31.172.83.181:8080/free/markets/' --data-urlencode '{"Cat":1,"OnlyActive":true,"NoZombie":true,"ToID":100000}'
```

But it's not working. I've tried a lot of options. Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

seems it works off GET data, not POST data. and your --data-urlencode parameter will provide POST data. Also a warning, that webserver is bugged, sending gzip compressed encoding even when the requesting client did not Accept-Encoding: gzip....

first off, you need to url encode the data. after that, you need to encode it for your shell.. which is different depending on what shell you're using. that said, this works in bash: `curl http://31.172.83.181:8080/free/markets/%7B%22Cat%22:1,%22OnlyActive%22:true,%22NoZombie%22:true,%22ToID%22:100000%7D --compressed`